# D3.js: Select Grand-Childs of List

Tags: arrays, select, d3.js, charts

I am new to D3.js and wonder about selecting child-elements.

What I want to do is selecting all "name"s of all the childs in the following data-structure:

```
{"id":"vehicle_usage_pie",
 "charts":[
     {"id":"EGBF/5",
      "title":"EGBF/5",
      "entries": [
           {"name":"Standzeit","value":32047},
           {"name":"Konditionierung","value":457},
           {"name":"Nutzung","value":6282}]
     },
     {"id":"EGBF/4",
      "title":"EGBF/4",
      "entries":[
           {"name":"Standzeit","value":2594},
           {"name":"Werkstatt","value":1570},
           {"name":"Nutzung","value":3558}]
     },
     {"id":"EGBF/3",
      "title":"EGBF/3",
      "entries":[
           {"name":"Nutzung","value":3582}]
     },
     {"id":"EGBF/2",
      "title":"EGBF/2",
      "entries":[
           {"name":"Konditionierung","value":8},
           {"name":"Nutzung","value":905}]
     }]
}
```

To draw it into a legend, the result should be:

```
[{"Standzeit"}, 
 {"Werkstatt"}, 
 {"Konditionierung"}, 
 {"Nutzung"}]
```

How can I do this with D3.js? I searched the api reference but still have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need D3 for this:

```
var names = [];
data.charts.forEach(function(d) {
  d.entries.forEach(function(e) {
    names.push(e.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: But then I get the titles of the charts and not of the entries?!

Comment: The children don't have `title` elements. Do you want the `name` elements?

Comment: Sorry. Yes the `name`-Element.